# Why DISPLAY variable constantly changing, and how can I determine what's the right value?

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, scripts, xbmc, display-manager

I use this script to launch XBMC:

```
#! /bin/bash
# Launch XBMC in windowed mode, then use wmctrl to remove the titlebar

DISPLAY=:0.0

# Start XBMC without blocking this script
xbmc &

# Wait for the XBMC window to appear
status=0
while [ $status -eq 0 ]
do
    sleep 1
 status=`wmctrl -x -l | grep "XBMC Media Center" | wc -l | awk '{print $1}'`
done

# Force XBMC window to fullscreen
#export SDL_VIDEO_FULLSCREEN_DISPLAY=1
wmctrl -x -t 0 -r XBMC Media Center.XBMC Media Center -b toggle,fullscreen
```

but the DISPLAY variable always changing... Why ? (I never change any configuration options) Sometimes it's 0.1, sometimes it's 0.0.
How should I modify the script to run whatever the value is, or what's a better solution ?

Comment: Are you logging in as multiple users (switch user) ?

Comment: I don't understand your question :D how can you log in as multiple users ? If you mean that multiple user are logged in to the same machine, yes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each user gets his or her own DISPLAY (Actually each X session), so they will change as users log in / log off and as you use the switch user feature.

Comment: ok, but how can I determine from the script which is the right DISPLAY right now ?

Comment: echo $DISPLAY or using $DISPLAY in a script will work for your current user. `w | awk '/user_name/ {print $3}'` will work for other users.

Comment: So I just remove the DISPLAY variable setting line. LOL. Thanks !